# Numeric Values not getting sorted by using substring in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My table has data as below  and when I am selecting the data using order by on the basis of first two characters of string it is not getting sorted properly.

```
1 - Property Damage 
11 - Legal Expenses
Delivery    
12 - Computer 
14 - Directors 
2 - Business
```

Below is the expected output:

```
1 - Property Damage 
2 - Business
11 - Legal Expenses
12 - Computer 
14 - Directors 
Delivery
```

I am using following query

```
Select column from table 
order by Substring(column,1,2);
```

Result set is like :

```
1 - Property Damage 
11 - Legal Expenses
12 - Computer 
14 - Directors 
2 - Business 
Delivery
```

My understanding is, that it is sorting on the basis ASCII value.
Is there any way to get the required output?

Comment: Does SQL Server have any collations with numeric sorting?

Comment: You are ordering the values as if they were text. You would need to cast your substring to an int or some other number.

Comment: Although that being said, you would ideally have two columns: one for the code and one for the description.

Comment: thats the problem I cannot sort as Int because some rows have text values in the beginning

Comment: **Don't combine multiple items within a single column.** If you has stored the number in a number column and the string in a separate string column you could always display them concatenated together, but sort and filter them without splitting them apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your order in 2, first part is to put columns that doesnt start with a numeric at the bottom - but still sorted while the numeric will still be undetermined (null). Second part will insert spaces so all the numeric has the same length before the first space.

```
SELECT col
FROM (values
  ('1 - Property Damage '),('11 - Legal Expenses'),('Delivery'),
  ('12 - Computer'),('14 - Directors'),('2 - Business ')) x(col)
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN col like '[0-9]%' then null else col end, 
  replicate(' ', 10-charindex(' ', col)) + col
```

Result:

```
col
1 - Property Damage 
2 - Business 
11 - Legal Expenses
12 - Computer
14 - Directors
Delivery
```

Answer (score 2):

A shorter answer

```
Select col
from table 
order by cast((Parsename(replace(col,' - ','.'), 2) ) as Int)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the return of SUBSTRING is a String, unlike Numeric sorting, where 2 follows 1, 11 follows 1 when sorting as Strings. Maybe you could use an IIF?

```
SELECT 
    [testcolumn]
FROM 
    [AdventureWorks].[dbo].[texttest]
ORDER BY 
    IIF(ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(testcolumn, 1, 2)) = 0, 799, CAST(SUBSTRING(testcolumn, 1, 2) AS int)),
    [testcolumn]
```

Comment: Sorry, IIF is only available in the MSSQL 2012 and above.

Comment: I used isnumeric in case statement. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you found a solution, and am happy the above helped you :)

Comment: FYI, IIF is a shorthand way for writing a CASE expression.  IIF is translated into CASE. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code:

The reason For **String datatype** It will sort values as like Sorting Alphabetical order i.e)abc

So simply **Convert Datatype** into **Int**

```
Create  TABLE #order
(
    name NVARCHAR(100)

)

INSERT INTO #ORDER VALUES('1 - Property Damage')
INSERT INTO #ORDER VALUES('2 - Business')
INSERT INTO #ORDER VALUES('11 - Legal Expenses')
INSERT INTO #ORDER VALUES('12 - Computer')
INSERT INTO #ORDER VALUES('14 - Directors 
Delivery')


select * from #order

Select name from #order 
order by convert(int,Substring(name,1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is being sorted correctly.  It is being sorted as *strings* rather than *numbers*.  If you want a numeric sort, then you need to sort numbers.  Your data structure suggests that you are combining two attributes into a single field.  You should think about fixing that.

That said, you can get the ordering you want:

```
order by (case when col like '_%' then '0' + left(col, 1)
               else left(col, 2)
          end)
```

The puts a leading "0" in front of the one digit numbers.